# removing the td with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to remove the td(please see commented td"to be removed") from this table without editing the HTML. 
Also, not using only the classes as I have the same classes in another tables that I don't need to be removed, so targeting the span id as well. Thanks in advance!

```
       <div id="pnlPersonalDetails2">

                  </div><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="surveyquestions">
              <tbody><tr>

                <td colspan="2" class="pd_question">
                    <span id="lbl2"></span>
                  </td>
                  </tr><tr>
                    <td class="pd_label">FIRST NAME<span class="red"> *</span></td>
                    <td>
                      <input name="Name微statictext_2" type="text" id="Name微statictext_2" class="pd_textbox">
                    </td>
                    <!-- To be removed
                    <td class="error_label">
                      <span id="ctl03" style="visibility:hidden;">Required Field</span>
                    </td>-->
                  </tr>

            </tbody></table>
    <div id="pnlPersonalDetails3">

          </div><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="surveyquestions">
      <tbody><tr>
 <!-- To be removed      
  <td colspan="2" class="pd_question">
            <span id="lbl3"></span>
          </td>-->
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="pd_label">LAST NAME<span class="red"> *</span></td>
        <td>
          <input name="Name微statictext_3" type="text" id="Name微statictext_3" class="pd_textbox">
        </td>
        <td class="error_label">
          <span id="ctl04" style="visibility:hidden;">Required Field</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

This is how it looks now

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3amF.png)

This is how I want to look after removing the commented td's

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prabo.png)

I have attached the entire code here https://codepen.io/duicug/pen/VGreQZ

Comment: With jQuery: `$("#ctl03").parent().hide()` or `$("#ctl03").closest('td').hide()`

Comment: I assume he wants to hide ANY td that has the comment "To be hidden" preceding it

Comment: @vsync where is Chris touching the HTML?`

Comment: @vsync "removing the td" and "without touching the HTML" is already contradictory, so I'll assume what I suggested is fine for now ("touching the HTML" probably means "changing it server-side")

Comment: OP: define "removing"

Comment: *"without touching the HTML"* - Um, the "to be hidden" content is commented out in the HTML you've shown, so...no need to remove those elements, they aren't there. It's not at all clear what you're asking here, or what attempt you've made to solve the problem. Selecting elements by ID is well-documented, as is finding the parent of an element, so...

Comment: what about `row.find('td:nth-of-type(<the index of the td to be hidden>)').hide();`

Comment: the commented td's are creating a space that I want to remove

Comment: @Duicug - No, commented-out `td` tags in a `tr` do not "create a space." Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and a clear description of it (you've said conflicting things, that you want to remove a `td` and that you want to remove "a space"). Ideally, make the MCVE **runnable** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: @Chris G without touching the HTML I meant without adding an id to the td for example

Comment: @Duicug We're talking about a commented-out `<td>` here, so even if it did create space (which it doesn't), it would be horizontally.

Comment: @Chris G  The reason why I put the td that I want to be removed in comments was to try to be specific but It looks like it wasn't a good idea. In my code, there is no comments in the HTML and I don't have access to edit the HTML at all directly.

Comment: @Duicug That's what I assumed, see the solution I posted in my first comment. I see that your `<td>`s are blocks, so I stand corrected; they do indeed create vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td id="hideTD" class="error_label" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <span id="ctl03" style="visibility:hidden;">Required Field</span>
</td>

<script>
  document.getElementById("hideTD").style.visibility = "hidden";
</script>
```

You can refer this website , good sample https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp

Hope that can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't help as you have added an id to the td which as I mentioned, I'm not allowed to edit the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="error_label">
  <span id="ctl03" style="visibility:hidden;">Required Field</span>
</td>

<td colspan="2" class="pd_question">
  <span id="lbl3"></span>
</td>

<script>
  document.getElementById("ctl03").parentElement.remove();
  document.getElementById("lbl3").parentElement.remove();
</script>
```

Comment: I just updated my question with the code. You can find it here https://codepen.io/duicug/pen/VGreQZ Still looking for a solution

Comment: This is a solution to your question "how to remove some TDs. To achieve a result which is demonstrated on the picture, you'll need to change the layout or style rules. Gap between firstname textbox and Lastname cell is (after removing desired cell) a <TD id=error_label>. You can remove that one too, or play more with css rules etc. Or pose new question.

Answer (score -1):

You could use querySelector to find the class such:

```
var target = document.querySelector("#pnlPersonalDetails2 .error_label");
```

There are then multiple ways to remove it from the DOM.

You could leave it in memory so that you can easily show it again later:

```
target.style.display = "none";  //Undo by setting to "" or to previous value
```

Or you could make it invisible which leaves it in memory and change the layout of surrounding contents:

```
target.style.visibility = "hidden";  //Undo by setting to "" or to previous value
```

Or you could completely remove it from the DOM:

```
target.parent.removeChild(target);
```

Answer (score -1):

try it with jquery:

```
$("#lbl2").toggle();
```

maybe this will help you?
   var el = document.getElementById('lbl2');
    el.parentElement.hidden = true;
or remove td
var el = document.getElementById('ctl03');
    el.parentElement.remove();